# Why doesn't my responsive menu RE-APPEAR as a list when the window gets larger?

Tags: javascript, html, list, mobile, menu

I have a sidebar list that I am turning into a simple drop-down accordion button responsively.  The problem is that when you resize the window smaller, open and then close the list, then resize the window larger.  The list does not re-appear in it's "desktop" form.

Demo: http://iamalecschmidt.com/newblog/

I'm using a simple bit of Javascript to switch out the Menu to switch the sidebar to a menu:

THE HTML:

```
<aside class="left-sidebar">

    <p class="intro">Hey! I’m Alec.</p>
    <p class="bio">
        I <a href="#">design</a> interfaces for websites & apps, I also 
        <a href="#">cook</a> and I am an aspiring front-end 
        <a href="#">developer</a>.
    </p>

    <div class="leftNavWrap">

        <ul class="leftNav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

        <a class="topicsButton" href="#">Topics &nbsp;<span>&#9660;</span></a>
        <a class="dribbbleIcon" href="#">Dribbble</a> 
        <a class="twitterIcon" href="#">Twitter</a>
    </div>
</aside>
```

THE JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // responsive menu
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    /* prepend menu icon */
    $('p.bio').append('<div id="menu-button"><p>Menu</p></div>');

    /* toggle nav */
    $("#menu-button").on("click", function(){
        $('div.leftNavWrap').slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: show some more code, where you are hide and show sidebar and top menu.

Answer (score 2):

`slideToggle` sets the style of the toggled element to `display:none` when closed ( http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/ ),  so when you resize back to 'desktop', the element stays hidden.

You'll need to check to see when the width expands past the 'desktop' breakpoint and make sure it is made visible, or use another method of show/hiding like toggling a class and applying the animation with css transitions.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem..

When you open your menu at top and do maximize, it will work. When you close your menu and maximize your window, there is a problem.

still **leftNavWrap's** display is none..

If you wan more help, show your code where you show and hide top menu and sidebar...